# Html datalist values from array from controller

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, laravel

I'm trying to make an input in HTML that when you write something it show you some possibilities. This possibilities are sent by my controller with an array.

This is my view:

```
<div class="form-group">
{!!Form::label('marca','Marca: ')!!}
{!!Form::text('marca',null, ['id' => 'marca', 'class' => 'form-control', 'onkeyup'=>'javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();', 'list'=>'lista'])!!}
<datalist id="lista"></datalist>
<br>
{!!Form::label('modelo','Modelo: ')!!}
{!!Form::text('modelo',null, ['id' => 'modelo', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Ingresa el modelo'])!!}
<br>
{!!Form::label('part_number','Part Number: ')!!}
{!!Form::text('part_number',null, ['id' => 'pn', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Ingresa el part number','onkeyup'=>'javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();'])!!}
<br>
{!!Form::label('coste','Coste: ')!!}
{!!Form::number('coste',null, ['id' => 'coste', 'step'=>'any', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Ingresa el coste del equipo'])!!}
<br>
{!!Form::label('caracteristicas','Características: ')!!}
{!!Form::text('caracteristicas',null, ['id' => 'caract', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Ingresa las características necesarias del part number'])!!}
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var marcas = $array;
var list = document.getElementById('lista');

marcas.forEach(function(item){
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = item;
    list.appendChild(option);
    });
```

This is my Controller:

```
public function create()
{
    $marcas = Modelos::Marcas();
    $array = array();

    foreach ($marcas as $marca) {
        $array[] = $marca->marca;
    }

    return view('modelos.create',compact('array'));
}
```

The console gives me the following error:

```
{Uncaught ReferenceError: $array is not defined at create:241}
```

Comment: `$array` is a php variable. you should probably echo it to the script. something like `var marcas = JSON.parse("<? echo json_encode($array); ?>")`.

Comment: With this change, gives me the following error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)`

Comment: Do you have any idea what you are doing or do you ask us to adapt a downloaded script to your needs?

Comment: Obviously your view is not parsed by PHP. Try to put something into `{!! ... !!}` tags. laravel documentation might provide helpful hints. I'm not familiar with laravel yet.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone Well, I know how to do it without a variable, in my script, I take it from others. If there are any better way to do it I would like learn. This is the reason wich I'm asking.

Comment: If i do like this `{!!Form::select('marcas',$array, null,['class' => 'form-control'])!!}` I haven't got problems, but I don't want a `select`. I want something like google search.

Comment: I can only guess, that `{!! ... !!}` is translated to something like `<?php echo ...?>`. You could try `var marcas = JSON.parse("{!! json_encode($array); !!}");`

Comment: If it doesn't work, assign it to some template variable first. (Providing that your "laravel" tag is applicable)

Comment: Thanks @Quasimodo'sclone It's works!! Thank so much. Now, if i can, I would like to ask you if it is a good way to do it or i can have problems or there are a better.

Comment: Since it depends on activated JavaScript in the client's browser, I personally would prefer to generate HTML code on server side. For your understanding: `$array` in the view template is generated by the name `'array'` in `view('modelos.create',compact('array'))`. It forms a data array `['array' : $array]`

Comment: correction: `compact` forms a data array `['array' => $array]` wich is assigned to the view, where it can be accessed as a variable.